# laravel translate using json file

Tags: json, laravel-6.2

I have multilingual application using laravel 6.2, and i want to translate terms imported from the database, so I use the following code:

```
<td>{{ __($specs) }}</td>
```

Examples of some specs in json file:

```
"Display" : "Monitor",
"Processor" : "Procesador",
"RAM" : "RAM",
"Rear Camera" : "Cámara trasera",
```

Until now, everything is fine.

But the problem is when importing variable expressions, for example:

```
5 inches
143 grams
```

I don't want to do this every time

```
  "5 inches" : "5 pulgadas",
  "6.5 inches" : "6.5 pulgadas",
  "5.61 inches" : "5.61 pulgadas",
  "6.54 inches" : "6.54 pulgadas",
  "7 inches" : "7 pulgadas",
  .
  .
  .
```

Is there a way to translate the word "inches" only once?

Comment: Is there any solution??

Comment: did you find a solution?? I think the easyest way is do something like: <p> {{ $size }} {{ __('inches') }}</p> ?

Comment: @StefanoMartini I need deeper than this
Because the method you suggested requires changing the database

Comment: sure? you can alway delete the inches from the string provided from the db ant the application side :)

Comment: @StefanoMartini specs array  ` a:6:{s:7:"Display";s:11:"6.95 inches";} `

Comment: Every time inches are in s:11?? How you pass the data to the view?

Comment: @StefanoMartini not every time ' a:6:{s:7:"Display";s:10:"6.4 inches" '.  using unserialize '@foreach (unserialize($z) as $x => $y)'

Comment: mmmh... you can try different way server side but surelly will impact performances, I don't know if you can put the database string like {!! $size !!} and if you find inches in the string made something like $size= value {{ __('inches')} but I don't know if blade when print size whit the raw directive !! understand to get the __('inches') string from the translation...